# How to get document vectors for a given topic in gensim

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I have about 9000 documents and I am using Gensim's `doc2vec` to embed my documents. My code is as follows:

```
from gensim.models import doc2vec
from collections import namedtuple

dataset = json.load(open(input_file))

docs = []
analyzedDocument = namedtuple('AnalyzedDocument', 'words tags')

for description in dataset:
    tags = [description[0]]
    words = description[1]
    docs.append(analyzedDocument(words, tags))

model = doc2vec.Doc2Vec(docs, vector_size = 100, window = 10, min_count = 1, workers = 4, epochs = 20)
```

I would like to get all the documents related to topic "deep learning". i.e. the documents that mainly have content related to deep learning. Is it possible to do this in doc2vec model in gensim?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there was a document in your training set that was a great example of "deep learning" – say, `docs[17]` – then after successful training you could ask for documents similar to that example document, and that could be roughly what you'd need. For example:

```
sims = model.docvecs.most_similar(docs[17].tags[0])
```

You'd then have in `sims` a ranked, scored list of the 10 most-similar documents to the `tag` for the target document.

Comment: thanks a lot for the great answer. Is there a more automated way of finding a great example of "deep learning"? The reason for this is that I took "deep learning" only as an example. But we have many topics to explore. :)

Comment: Is word2vec is also trained with doc2vec and can we use that to find the best document in the doc2vec model? Looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: If you've preprocessed your text in a way that has turned multi-word phrases (like `'deep learning'`) into single word-tokens (like `'deep_learning'`), and if you've used a `Doc2Vec` mode were both word- and doc-vectors are co-trained into the same 'space', then the vector for word `'deep_learning'` (& other topics) may be somewhat useful for your purposes. But even better would be hand-selected example documents, or categorizations from some existing system matching whatever **you** need 'deep learning' to mean.

Comment: For example, Wikipedia has a 'deep learning' category – https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Deep_learning – and Arxiv has categories like `cs.AI` (artificial intelligence) & `cs.LG` (machine learning), but nothing specifically 'deep learning'. To the extent you can find reliably-labeled docs, you can add them to your corpus and/or use them as examplars/queries. Note, though, that reducing a topic to just a "single summary point" (1 vector) may not be as good as having a range-of-examples, covering exotically-shaped areas in the high-dim doc-vector space, for truly modeling a category.

Comment: thanks a lot for the valuable details. today I did bit of manual annotation to identify best suited documents for the topics. For example, suppose for `deep learning` topic, the best suited document tag is `paper_3286`. Is it correct if I use it this way? `sims = model.docvecs.most_similar(docs["paper_3286"].tags[0])` Looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: Since `docs["paper_3286"].tags[0]` should just be `"paper_3286"`, you could simplify that to `sims = model.docvecs.most_similar("paper_3286")`. You can also provide multiple positive examples & it will average-them-together before returning docs closest-to-that-average. EG: `most_similar(positive=['paper_3286', 'paper_1234', 'paper_4077`])`. (This might be helpful, or it might, by collapsing the variety of the 3 examples into a single point, be less interesting than looking at the nearest-N to each example separately. You'd have to test what works well for your needs.)

Comment: thanks a lot. It is really great to hear that we can input multiple documents at once as `most_similar(positive=['paper_3286', 'paper_1234', 'paper_4077'])`. Just curious to know if there is a limit to the number of documents we can specify or can we input as much as we want? Thank you :)

Comment: There's no enforced cap on how many items can be in the `positive` list - so if you can construct the list, it'll probably work fine passed-in! (But again: averaging-many-together to a single-point may oversimplify the areas covered by multiple examples, compared to other techniques.)